# how to fetch value for dynamic textarea

Tags: php, textarea

i want to fetch comments on some ans by their question_id or ans_id, but text arez coming dynamicaly so i am confused how to fetch comment for exact ans
look at my textarea field[image]

here 70,66 are the ans_id
so i want to fetch comment whose ans_id is 70 or 66, at the position of same question,
here is my comment table
[image]

i applied this code for get the comment value for each textarea
echo $loot="select* from comment where answer_id='$ans_id' && activation=1";
$root=mysql_query($loot);

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($root))
{

?>
<h1><?php echo $row['comments']; ?></h1>
<?php
}
?>
```

and getting result like this

[image]

it is fetching only one value for one id
i thing you might have understand my problem...thanx in advance, any recommendation will highly responded...

Answer (score 1):

Name your text areas in array notation. example

`<textarea name="ddd[90]" id="ddd" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>`.

Then you can access text area content like bellow when submitted.

```
  echo $_POST['ddd'][90];
```